# ffmpeg static link in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, static-libraries, static-linking

I have build ffmpeg static library on Windows. It seems that everything completed with success. The result of build are following files:

```
libavcodec.a
libavdevice.a
libavfilter.a
libavformat.a
libavutil.a
libswscale.a
```

I tried to specify above files in Linker->Input in my C++ libray project, but linking fails. Following is build output:

```
1>libavutil.a(samplefmt.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavutil.a(error.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavutil.a(log.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavutil.a(utils.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavutil.a(avstring.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavutil.a(bprint.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavformat.a(id3v2.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavutil.a(opt.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavutil.a(dict.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavutil.a(pixdesc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavcodec.a(ratecontrol.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavcodec.a(qsv.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavformat.a(utils.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavformat.a(aviobuf.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavcodec.a(utils.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavcodec.a(ffv1enc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavcodec.a(exif.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_img_wrap
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_version_str
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_version_str
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_build_config
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_build_config
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_err_to_string
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_error
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_error
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_error_detail
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_error_detail
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_destroy
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_destroy
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_control_
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_enc_init_ver
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_enc_config_default
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_encode
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_get_cx_data
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxenc.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_vp8_cx
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_dec_init_ver
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_decode
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_get_frame
1>libavcodec.a(libvpxdec.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vpx_codec_vp8_dx_algo
1>libavutil.a(opt.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsscanf
1>libavutil.a(parseutils.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsscanf
1>libavcodec.a(h264_sei.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsscanf
1>libavcodec.a(ratecontrol.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsscanf
1>libavcodec.a(qsv.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsscanf
1>libavformat.a(id3v2.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vsscanf
1>libavutil.a(log.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___acrt_iob_func
1>libavutil.a(log.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___stdio_common_vfprintf
```

What could be missing here?

Comment: Are .a files VS libraries in Windows? Check for .lib files.

Comment: .lib are generated when ffmpeg is not static build.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2049?cversion=2&cnum_hist=5

Comment: It is the same with --extra-cflags="-MD" option..